# How can i see in which tkinter canvas shape is clicked?

Tags: python, events, canvas, tkinter, click

I have a simple program, with some buttons who are not made by Tkinter self. I just made them with `canvas.create_rectangle` and things like that. But the problem is: The buttons can move. I can do it like this:

```
if event.x > c.coords(button)[0] and event.y > c.coords(button)[1] \
and event.x < c.coords(button)[2] and event.y < c.coords(button)[3]:
    ::line of code::
```

But is there a shorter way? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use tag binding: `canvas.tag_bind(<tag>, '<1>', callback)`, just replace `<tag>` by the item id of your button. Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_click(event):
    print('click')
    canvas.move(button1, 10, 5)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

button1 = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50, fill='red')
canvas.tag_bind(button1, '<1>', on_click)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This totally work, but I have some concern as I using a shape to follow mouse position and act like cursor. Every time I click, it just keep detect that cursor shape.
Is there any way to make these code  ignore the cursor shape?
I know that I should not ask a question in comment but I got ban for asking new question.

Comment: @Mlab If you are using a shape as a cursor, I think the tag binding won't work as your cursor will be the active item, not the one you want to click on. You will have to use a workaround, maybe a binding on the canvas combined with the use of `.find_overlapping(x, y)` to check which item you are clicking on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the canvas tag `current`, which specifies the item under the cursor. From the official tcl/tk documentation:

> The tag **current** is managed automatically by Tk; it applies to the current item, which is the topmost item whose drawn area covers the position of the mouse cursor (different item types interpret this in varying ways; see the individual item type documentation for details). If the mouse is not in the canvas widget or is not over an item, then no item has the current tag.

Comment: How to find which widget has the tag current?

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer: You can get a list of items with any tag with the `find_withtag` method (eg: `canvas.find_withtag("current")`)

Comment: yeah actually I saw your reply on another question later and figured it out! Thx bro!